# Lie derivative of a scalar and PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I posted this on the physics stackexchange, but they told me to post here, as it may be more relevant.

I am reading about differential geometry, and in particular the Lie derivative and its relation to (relativistic) hydrodynamics. In particular, I was wondering if, given two scalar functions $f(\mathbf{x}),~g(\mathbf{x})$, it is possible to solve the following equation:

$$\mathcal{L}_Z[f]=Z^\mu\partial_\mu f=g,$$

where $Z=Z^\mu\partial_\mu$ is an arbitrary vector field. Since I am thinking of hydrodynamics here, I am considering the manifold associated to $Z$ to be Euclidean space, but I would be interested to know how it works for arbitrary manifolds.

Is their a theorem that guaranties the existence of a solution? I am okay with existence, I don't necessarily need a way to find the solution. If there is no such proof, what are the restriction one needs to impose on $Z$? If there is a proof, is it also valid for tensor quantities, ie is there a solution to

$$\mathcal{L}_Z[f^{\mu_1...\mu_n}_{\nu_1...\nu_m}]=g^{\mu_1...\mu_n}_{\nu_1...\nu_m}.$$

Comment: Solve for what,  given $f,g$ do you want to solve it for $Z$?

Comment: Knowing $g,Z$ I want to solve it for $f$

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98281/2451

Comment: I posted a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554988/solutions-of-a-differential-equation-with-lie-derivative Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros of $Z$ form an obvious obstruction, as $g$ must vanish there also, to order no less then $Z$. Consider for example, in one variable, 
$Z=x^2\partial_x,$ $g(x)=x.$

Away from the zeros of $Z$, your equation can be solved, locally, for any $g$, as $Z$ can be ''rectified'', i.e. one can find coordinates $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ so that $Z$ is the partial wrt $x_1$, and the equation is solved by integrating $g$ wrt $x_1$.

Globally, even away from zeros of $Z$, there might be obstructions, if $Z$ has closed integral curves. Consider for example in the plane, $Z=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y$.

Comment: I posted a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554988/solutions-of-a-differential-equation-with-lie-derivative . Could you please have a look at the slightly different conditions?