# Solutions of a differential equation with Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I have a vector field $F$ that generates an ergodic flow on a compact manifold $X$. Given a scalar field $f$, I would like to solve the equation:

$$ \mathcal{L}^F (\varphi) = F^\mu \partial_\mu \varphi = f$$

for $\varphi$. Here $\mathcal{L}_F$ is the Lie derivative along $F$.

At least, I would like to find a solution for almost every point of $X$.

What are the conditions on $f$ such that a solution can be found?

A necessary, trivial condition is that the average of $f$ vanishes, $\left<f\right>=0$. Is this condition sufficient for finding a solution almost everywhere?

The question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668327/lie-derivative-of-a-scalar-and-pde), but, with the additional hypothesis connected to ergodicity, the objections raised in the answers to that question should not hold.

I am looking for a proof of existence of a solution or a counter-example. Literature references are particularly welcome!